# Can any one tell me how to show products on shop page by category in asc order

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I am willing to show product on shop page by category order i tried below code but not get any solution yet.

add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby',    'custom_default_catalog_orderby');
function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {

```
    return 'product_cat'; // Can also use title and price
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) will return an array of categories. If you want product categories, you must specifiy the 'product_cat' taxonomy.

```
get_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ) );
```

Comment: thankyou mate but i want to show the products from the category in same manner as category set in backend

Comment: Are you saying that you want to return the products from a specific category?

Comment: That's right and product show category wise in same order as category set in background like ex: i have set "Dog" first and category "Cat" second than on shop shows Dog product first and Cat Second.